# Cannot find any issues with my code but, I have a eight error messages. Four CS1519, two CS1001, CS1022 and CS8124

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
//using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IPlayer
{
    Rigidbody2D MyRigidbody { get; set; }
    float Speed { get; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{{{nameof(DebuggerDisplay)}(),nq}}")]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour, IPlayer
{

    private Rigidbody2D _myRigidbody;
    private float speed;

    public float Speed => speed;
    private void SetSpeed() => speed = value;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()=>

        _myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

    public Rigidbody2D MyRigidbody { get => _myRigidbody; set => _myRigidbody = value; }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        _myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move = speed, _myRigidbody.velocity.y);

    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update

        _myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();**Whole line seems to have errors Three CS1519 errors and One CS8124 error**



    // Update is called once per frame
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        _myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move = speed, _myRigidbody.velocity.y);
        **Whole line has errors↑ Two CS1001 errors and One CS1519 error**   
    }** error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected**

}
```

The Code was for a project I am working on for my coursework and is supposed to use the left and right arrows keys to move the GameObject in a horizontal position. Am only a beginner when it comes to c# and could not find anything that was very helpful elsewhere online. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Please write the full error message and show the lines the come from. We don't memorize error numbers. In addition, it looks like you close the Update method, then continue writing statements.

Answer (score 1):

They are all compiler errors because the code is jumbled up. It's like someone copy pasted your code and messed it all up. Even the comments were the same.

```
using System.Collections;//Namespace was commented out.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IPlayer
{
    Rigidbody2D MyRigidbody { get; set; }
    float Speed { get; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{{{nameof(DebuggerDisplay)}(),nq}}")]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour, IPlayer
{

    private Rigidbody2D _myRigidbody;
    private float speed;

    public float Speed => speed;
    private void SetSpeed() => speed = value;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()=>

        _myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

    public Rigidbody2D MyRigidbody { get => _myRigidbody; set => _myRigidbody = value; }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        _myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(move = speed, _myRigidbody.velocity.y);

    }

    // This particular line may need to be called elsewhere but, it's a 
    // value assignment without a codeblock. Place this inside the update
    // method or comment it out. 
    // (Probably delete it since you are assigning this in the delegate named start.)
    //   _myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    // The other code block wasn't named or demarked with anything and it 
    // was literally a carbon copy of your Update method.
}
```